# pyspark merge import column from one df to another based on matching data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am extremely new to working with data frames. 
 I have two frames.

One is called `new` the other is called `existing`.

`new` has a single column called ID. `existing` has three columns: ID, color, size.

I want to operate on these frames such that when a row can be found in `new` with the same ID as a row in `existing` we add the value of the color column (but not the size column) to the `new` data frame.  If no match is found I would like to assign a random value to the color column of `new`

It occurs to me that I can do this with rdd.map but I am trying to restrict myself to working with frames because I'm told it's more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a join, a left join to be precise:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
new_df = new_df.join(existing_df, "id", "left_outer") \
               .select(new_df.id, f.coalesce(f.col("color"), f.rand())
```

The coalesce function will give you color if it is not null (i.e. if there is a match) or a random number. You probably need to map the random number to your color spectrum somehow (dependent on what representation you have there).

As a general note: Using dataframes and the spark-sql API is way faster than doing RDD operations